# How to make seat booking layout like redbus

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview

I am working on a bus booking app and I want to add seat booking layout like in the Red Bus App. I design layout using GridView but it looks like

[image]  [image]

<sup>*What I have*</sup>                                    <sup>*What I want*</sup>

I need less space between Seat 1 and Seat 2 then big space between Seat 2 and 3 and again space between seat 3 and seat 4 as seat 1 and 2. And in last row i need 5 seats. I need exactly same as red bus layout.

**XML**

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/seatLayoutLowerMain"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/seatLegendLayout"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10.0dip"
            android:background="@drawable/seat_layout_border"
            android:paddingBottom="5.0dp"
            android:paddingRight="5.0dp" >

            <GridView
                android:id="@+id/gridView1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/driver"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                android:columnWidth="100dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:numColumns="5"
                android:stretchMode="columnWidth" >
            </GridView>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/driver"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/gridView1"
                android:layout_marginRight="20.0dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5.0dp"
                android:background="@drawable/steering_icon"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >
            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
```

**SeatSelection Activity**

```
public class SeatSelection extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener{

GridView gridView;
ArrayList<Item> gridArray = new ArrayList<Item>();
CustomGridViewAdapter customGridAdapter;
public Bitmap seatIcon;
public Bitmap seatSelect;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_seat_selection);

    seatIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.seat_layout_screen_nor_avl);
    seatSelect = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.seat_layout_screen_nor_std);
    totalSeat(49);

    gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
    customGridAdapter = new CustomGridViewAdapter(this, R.layout.seatrow_grid, gridArray);
    gridView.setAdapter(customGridAdapter);
    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
}

public void totalSeat(int n)
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
    {
        gridArray.add(new Item(seatIcon, "Seat " + i));

    }
}

public void seatSelected(int pos)
{
    gridArray.remove(pos);
    gridArray.add(pos, new Item(seatSelect, "Selected"));
    customGridAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void seatDeselcted(int pos)
{

    gridArray.remove(pos);
    int i = pos + 1;
    gridArray.add(pos, new Item(seatIcon, "Seat" + i));
    customGridAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
{

    Item item = gridArray.get(position);
    Bitmap seatcompare = item.getImage();
    if (seatcompare == seatIcon)
    {
        seatSelected(position);
    }
    else
    {
        seatDeselcted(position);

    }

}

}
```

**CustomGridViewAdapter**

```
public class CustomGridViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item>
{

Context context;
int layoutResourceId;
ArrayList<Item> data = new ArrayList<Item>();

public CustomGridViewAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<Item> data)
{
    super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.context = context;
    this.data = data;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    View row = convertView;
    RecordHolder holder = null;

    try
    {
        if (row == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

            holder = new RecordHolder();
            holder.txtTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.item_text);
            holder.imageItem = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.item_image);
            row.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (RecordHolder) row.getTag();
        }

        Item item = data.get(position);
        holder.txtTitle.setText(item.getTitle());
        holder.imageItem.setImageBitmap(item.getImage());
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return row;
}

public static class RecordHolder
{
    public TextView txtTitle;
    public ImageView imageItem;

}
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to use a gridview here, instead you can dynamically create this view with the combinations of linear layout and imageview..

You can check the sample here..
https://github.com/varunjohn/Booking-Seats-Layout-Sample

Full Code here..
https://github.com/varunjohn/Booking-Seats-Layout-Sample/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/varun/seatlayout/MainActivity.java

```
 String seats = 
          "_UUUUUUAAAAARRRR_/"
        + "_________________/"
        + "UU__AAAARRRRR__RR/"
        + "UU__UUUAAAAAA__AA/"
        + "AA__AAAAAAAAA__AA/"
        + "AA__AARUUUURR__AA/"
        + "UU__UUUA_RRRR__AA/"
        + "AA__AAAA_RRAA__UU/"
        + "AA__AARR_UUUU__RR/"
        + "AA__UUAA_UURR__RR/"
        + "_________________/"
        + "UU_AAAAAAAUUUU_RR/"
        + "RR_AAAAAAAAAAA_AA/"
        + "AA_UUAAAAAUUUU_AA/"
        + "AA_AAAAAAUUUUU_AA/"
        + "_________________/";
```

Create a string like this, the code below will make the booking layout out of it..

```
LinearLayout layoutSeat = new LinearLayout(this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new 
 LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
 ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    layoutSeat.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    layoutSeat.setLayoutParams(params);
    layoutSeat.setPadding(8 * seatGaping, 8 * seatGaping, 8 * 
 seatGaping, 8 * seatGaping);
    layout.addView(layoutSeat);

    LinearLayout layout = null;

    int count = 0;

    for (int index = 0; index < seats.length(); index++) {
        if (seats.charAt(index) == '/') {
            layout = new LinearLayout(this);
            layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
            layoutSeat.addView(layout);
        } else if (seats.charAt(index) == 'U') {
            count++;
            TextView view = new TextView(this);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(seatSize, seatSize);
            layoutParams.setMargins(seatGaping, seatGaping, seatGaping, seatGaping);
            view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            view.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 2 * seatGaping);
            view.setId(count);
            view.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_seats_booked);
            view.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            view.setTag(STATUS_BOOKED);
            view.setText(count + "");
            view.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 9);
            layout.addView(view);
            seatViewList.add(view);
            view.setOnClickListener(this);
        } else if (seats.charAt(index) == 'A') {
            count++;
            TextView view = new TextView(this);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(seatSize, seatSize);
            layoutParams.setMargins(seatGaping, seatGaping, seatGaping, seatGaping);
            view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            view.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 2 * seatGaping);
            view.setId(count);
            view.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_seats_book);
            view.setText(count + "");
            view.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 9);
            view.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            view.setTag(STATUS_AVAILABLE);
            layout.addView(view);
            seatViewList.add(view);
            view.setOnClickListener(this);
        } else if (seats.charAt(index) == 'R') {
            count++;
            TextView view = new TextView(this);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(seatSize, seatSize);
            layoutParams.setMargins(seatGaping, seatGaping, seatGaping, seatGaping);
            view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            view.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 2 * seatGaping);
            view.setId(count);
            view.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_seats_reserved);
            view.setText(count + "");
            view.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 9);
            view.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            view.setTag(STATUS_RESERVED);
            layout.addView(view);
            seatViewList.add(view);
            view.setOnClickListener(this);
        } else if (seats.charAt(index) == '_') {
            TextView view = new TextView(this);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(seatSize, seatSize);
            layoutParams.setMargins(seatGaping, seatGaping, seatGaping, seatGaping);
            view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            view.setText("");
            layout.addView(view);
        }
    }
```

Comment: @varunjohn1990 your provided sample is very useful. How can we show seat number as A1, A2, A3.... in first row and B1, B2, B3 in second row? Please help me.

Comment: @Pooja : this can be done easily.. in my sample '/' represents end of the row.. take 2 variable 1 holds the the row count and other for holding row seat count, in if statement you'll find '/' body just initial the 2 variable accordingly and set the text..

Comment: @varunjohn1990 Thanks for reply. I am primary level developer and I tried a lot but its not working. I know something is wrong from my side but pls help me. Give me some example code.

Comment: @Pooja : connect me on mail - varunjohn1990@gmail.com