# Gridview item set based on matrix position [row][column]

Tags: java, android

[image]I need to design the bus seat view in android application and I have seat positions in matrix format. For example

```
a1.row=4;
a1.column=5;
```

I only need to set those seats in gridview based on their matrix position. Other spaces will be blank or empty in matrix. After showing these seat view if I choose specific seat then that seat related object will be added in a list of object and if I deselect it will be removed from the list of object. Can anyone help me to find out a solution for this ? Is it possible to implement this using gridview but I will set the item in grid view using its matrix position

Comment: you can check this answer, it might help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49999901/how-to-make-seat-booking-layout-like-redbus/51838864

Comment: that seat view is based on string format.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

Activityclass

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rv_list);
        showSeatList();
    }

    private void showSeatList()
    {

        List<SeatModel> seatModels = new ArrayList<>();

        seatModels.add(new SeatModel("1","A",false));
        seatModels.add(new SeatModel("2","B",false));
        seatModels.add(new SeatModel("3","C",false));
        seatModels.add(new SeatModel("4","D",false));
        seatModels.add(new SeatModel("5","E",false));
        seatModels.add(new SeatModel("6","F",false));
        seatModels.add(new SeatModel("7","G",false));
        seatModels.add(new SeatModel("8","H",false));
        seatModels.add(new SeatModel("9","I",false));
        seatModels.add(new SeatModel("10","J",false));

        SeatSelectionAdapter adapter = new SeatSelectionAdapter(this,seatModels);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 5));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

}
```

Adapter Class

```
public class SeatSelectionAdapter  extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SeatSelectionAdapter.ViewHolder>
{
    private List<SeatModel> seatModelList;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private Context context;

    public SeatSelectionAdapter(Context context, List<SeatModel>models)
    {
        this.seatModelList = models;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public SeatSelectionAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.model_seat,parent,false);
        return new SeatSelectionAdapter.ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull SeatSelectionAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        SeatModel model = seatModelList.get(position);
        holder.setData(model);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return seatModelList.size();
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        private CardView cardView;
        private LinearLayout lnLayout;
        private TextView tvSeat;

        private ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            tvSeat = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_seat);
            cardView = view.findViewById(R.id.cv_card);
            lnLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.ln_layout);
        }

        @SuppressLint({"SetTextI18n", "ClickableViewAccessibility"})
        private void setData(final SeatModel model)
        {
            tvSeat.setText(model.getSeat());
            if(model.isSelect())
                lnLayout.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
            else lnLayout.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));

            cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(model.isSelect())
                    {
                        model.setSelect(false);
                        Toast.makeText(context,"Seat not selected",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    else{
                        model.setSelect(true);
                        Toast.makeText(context,"Seat selected",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }



                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });

        }
    }
}
```

Model Class

```
public class SeatModel
{
    private String id,seat;
    private boolean isSelect;

    public SeatModel(String id, String seat, boolean isSelect) {
        this.id = id;
        this.seat = seat;
        this.isSelect = isSelect;
    }

    public boolean isSelect() {
        return isSelect;
    }

    public void setSelect(boolean select) {
        isSelect = select;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getSeat() {
        return seat;
    }

    public void setSeat(String seat) {
        this.seat = seat;
    }
}
```

Comment: I need to arrange the seats based on their matrix position in grid. Not like one after one. In image you can see it is a 9x4 grid and [0,0],[0,1], [1,0],[1,1] positions are empty

Comment: Seat model should have these properties
 seat.row=4;
 seat.column=5;